# Why the intersections of compactly many open sets are open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In the some papers, claim that if $K$ is a compact set in a space and for every $k\in K$, $U_k$ is an open set in topological space $X$, then $\bigcap \{ U_k: k\in K\}$ is an open set in $X$.

The proof of this claim is not clear for me.
I am so tankful if you help me.

Comment: What paper is claiming that?

Comment: @Didier, I can not access the following

Comment: https://eudml.org/doc/115797

Comment: L. Nachbin. Compact unions of closed subsets are closed and compact intersections of open subsets are open. Portugal. Math., 49(4):403–409, 1992.

Comment: The statement is very very false.

Comment: The paper assumes additional conditions!

Comment: See also the paper [Intersections of compactly many open sets are open](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.06050).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim is false:

The set $K= \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \Bbb N, n \geqslant 1\} \cup \{0\}$ is compact.
Let $U_0 = \Bbb R$ and for $n \geqslant 1$, $U_{\frac{1}{n}} = (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$.
For each $k \in K$, $U_k$ is open in $\Bbb R$, while $\bigcap_{k\in K}U_k = \{0\}$ is not open.

The statement in the article linked in the comments is not those you give.
It is the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $\Lambda$ be a compact space and $(G_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ be a family of subsets of $X$.
> **Assume that the graph $G$ of this family is open in $X\times \Lambda$.**
> Then $\cap_{\lambda\in \Lambda} G_{\lambda}$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am studying the semiflow $(T, X)$, where $T$ is topologically semigroup and $X$ is regular space such that $T$ continuously act on $X$ . This mean that the map $T\times X\to X$ by $(t, x)\mapsto tx$ is a continuous action.

Comment: In this semiflow, $K$ is compact set in $T$ and $\{U_k: k\in K\}\subseteq X$ is a collection of open sets in $X$. Can I say that $\bigcap\{U_k: k\in K\}$ is an open set?

Comment: This is known as [Tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma)

Comment: @ronno, Thanks a lot for your reply. Do you mean that I can used tube lemma to show that if $(T, X)$ is a semiflow and $K$ is a compact set in $T$, then                     $\bigcap\{U_k:k\in K\}$ is an open set in $X$?

Comment: No, I just meant that the statement quoted in this answer is (equivalent to) the tube lemma.